# Create line from point `idx=N` on a curve to point `idx=N` on another curve (3.0 Geo Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm toying around with Geometry Nodes and I would like to know if this possible:

- I've an input curve `A`.
- I resample it to `N` points.
- I duplicate the curve (let's name it `B`) and scale it down.
- *[Up to this point everything OK]*
- Now, I would like to create `N` lines, so that I connect `idx=0` from curve `A` to `idx=0` from curve `B`. This should be done once for each pair of points `A(idx) => B(idx)`. It should work with any arbitrary amount of points.

So is this possible? If so, what concepts/nodes I should be using?

Thanks!

---

This is my best guess… but since `Capture Attribute` outputs a field I can't use it in `Curve Line`…

[image]

Comment: Looks useful, I'll try it later, thanks!